# Firebase Firestore - unable to get the value of a field in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore defined as shown in the image
[image]

The field ***zaaidata*** is an object. I want to use the value of ***tot*** and ***van*** in a response that is sent to my chatbot in Dialogflow with a webhook.

I managed to query the document, but I am unable to retrieve the specific values. I already tried this:

- doc.data["zaaidata"]["van"]
- doc.data("zaaidata")("van")
- doc.data.get("zaaidata")["van"]

Here is my index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();

exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    let parameters = req.body.result.parameters; 
    var groentenRef = db.collection('groenten').doc(parameters.groente);

    var query = groentenRef.get()
        .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                response = "No such document!";
            } else {
                response = "Je kan zaaien tussen " + doc.data["zaaidata"]["van"] + " en " + doc.data["zaaidata"]["tot"];
            }
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ "speech": response, "displayText": response}));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        }); 
});
```

Can someone help me on this, please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `doc.data()` to get the JSON object representing the document. So `doc.data().zaaidata.van` would get the from date. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: This is correct.  `JSON.stringify(doc.data())` will render the object as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this

```
response = "Je kan zaaien tussen " + doc.data().zaaidata.van + " en " + doc.data().zaaidata.tot;
```